# почему в веб-интерфейсе вылазит ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: html, css, html5

я пишу веб-интерфейс для скрипта питон и для перехода между страницами использую кнопку типа `<a href="main.html>"`  и когда я возвращаюсь на начальную страницу и снова нажимаю кнопку, кнопка перестает работать и вылазит ошибка `Нет связи с сайтом  Хост localhost отклонил запрос на соединение. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Код первой страницы

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btndiv">
    <a href="second.html" class="buttons_buttons--olx">Запустити</a>
    <a href="delete_list.html" class="buttons_buttons--prom">Зупинити</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Код второй страницы

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reductor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="divbt">
    <form action="1_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--rozetka" id="Rozetka">Rozetka</button>
    </form>
    <form action="2_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--prom" id="Prom">Prom</button>
    </form>
    <form action="3_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--hotline" id="Hotline">Hotline</button>
    </form>
    <form action="4_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--horoshop" id="Horoshop">Horoshop</button>
    </form>
    <form action="5_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--olx" id="Olx">Olx</button>
    </form>
    <form action="6_2page.html">
      <button class="buttons_buttons--bit3x" id="Bitrix">Bitrix24</button>
    </form>
    <a href="start.html" class="btn--back">Назад</a>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Третий файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="eel.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btndiv">
        <span id="spam">Запущені процесси
        </span>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b2'>Зупинити Rozetka</a>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b1'>Зупинити Prom</a>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b5'>Зупинити Hotline</a>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b4'>Зупинити Horoshop</a>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b6'>Зупинити Olx</a>
        <a href="" class="btn--del" id='b3'>Зупинити bit3x24</a>

        <a href="" class="btn--start" id="dell--start" onclick="check()">Обновити</a>
        <a href="stop_start.html" class="btn--back">Назад</a>

    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    async function check(){
       eel.actiwe()();

    }
    check()
    eel.expose(hide_unhide);
    function hide_unhide(a, b){
        console.log('yes')
        document.getElementsByClassName('btn--del')[0].style='visibility: hidden;'
        if( b === 1){
            document.querySelector(a).style.visibility='visible';
            console.log('set' + a + 'visible')
        }
        console.log(a, b)
    }
    



    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Зачем вам формы на второй странице? Сделайте ссылками просто, тогда сервер не будет отклонять запрос с формы, которую не отправили фактически.

Comment: Я убрал формы на второй странице и вместо нее поставил `<a>` и оно работает.

Comment: однако переход на третий файл все равно ломаеться